# Vue do not save clicked element style

Tags: vue.js

I am generating small list of items. After click on every single item it should change style. Only one item can be selected. If you click on another item first item reverse to default value.

I have follow code:

```
<div class="LngList">
    <div class="lng" v-for="item in languages">
        <button :class="[ isLangSelected ? 'ui inverted basic button' : 'ui inverted red basic button' ]" @click=LangSelect(item.lang)>{{item.lang}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My method:

```
data: function (){
return {
        isLangSelected: false,
        mycode: "",
        languages: [
            {lang:'D'},
            {lang:'C#'},
            {lang:'Python'}
        ],
        selectedLanguage: ""
    }
},
methods: {
LangSelect(lang)
{
    this.selectedLanguage = lang;
    if(this.selectedLanguage.length != "")
    {
        this.isLangSelected = !this.isLangSelected;
    }
}
}
```

But when I am clicking outside the button I am losing selected style.

I did small gif to show the problem:
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that from the code you posted *all* the buttons will be selected or not whenever one is clicked. Is it the same code where you have the problem?

Comment: Yes the code is same.

Comment: Im confused then. How do you maintain one selected language? Here is a pen with your exact code. All of them get the same class. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GENrrP?editors=1010

Comment: Here is copy-past of my current code https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/ceec27205d7f2992ca24626cea595875
I did gif from it.

Comment: Same deal, all are select or not. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GENrrP?editors=1010

Comment: Agree with BertEvans - you should probably be checking selectedLanguage instead.  Also, your gif output isn't matching your gist.  IOTW, not seeing the output of 'true' and 'fchanged' so hard to know for certain if there's something else we're not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible of course with buttons, but why don't you use a radio input instead? Having only one item selected, that's what they are done for.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      languages: [{
          lang: 'D'
        },
        {
          lang: 'C#'
        },
        {
          lang: 'Python'
        }
      ],
      selectedLanguage: ''
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isLangSelected() {
      return this.selectedLanguage !== '';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label v-for="lang in languages">
    <input type="radio" name="languages"
      v-model="selectedLanguage" :value="lang.lang">
    <span>{{lang.lang}}</span>
  </label>
  <div v-if="isLangSelected">
    Selected language is: {{ selectedLanguage }}
  </div>
</div>
```